# Embedding outofbox portlets in Custom portlet

Tags: embed, liferay, portlet

I m trying to embed calender portlet in my custom portlet. But not able to accomplish this. I am getting below error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
    ServletException in '/html/common/themes/portlet.jsp': 

File &quot;/html/common/themes/portlet.jsp&quot; not found
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
```

This is my class:

```
public class Hello extends MVCPortlet {

    public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) 
                    throws IOException, PortletException {

        final String portletId = "47"; //hello world portlet id

        final ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        HttpServletRequest req = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);

        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) request.getAttribute(PortletServlet.PORTLET_SERVLET_RESPONSE);

        ServletContext servletContext = req.getSession().getServletContext();

        PortletPreferences prefs = null;

        try {
            // get the portlet preferences
            prefs = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletPreferences(req, portletId);
        } catch (PortalException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("portlet preferences are " + prefs.toString());

        //method 3
        PortletPreferences originalPrefs = null;

        try {
            originalPrefs = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getStrictLayoutPortletSetup(
            themeDisplay.getLayout(), portletId);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        PortletPreferences targetPrefs = null;

        try {
            targetPrefs = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getStrictLayoutPortletSetup(
            themeDisplay.getLayout(), portletId);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : targetPrefs.getMap().entrySet()) {
            targetPrefs.reset(entry.getKey());
        }

        for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : originalPrefs.getMap().entrySet()) {
            targetPrefs.setValues(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        // Store preferencec.
        targetPrefs.store();

        try {
            //finally render the portlet
            final String portletHtml = RuntimePortletEmbedUtil.renderPortlet(request, response, portletId, "");
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any insights to portlet embedding, I have already tried working on suggestions from [this blog](http://www.devatwork.nl/2011/07/liferay-embedding-portlets-in-your-portlet/) but no help.

Any suggestions or a way to accomplish this?

I guess there are issues to get the correct portlet preferences and authority to add a portlet over a targeted portlet.

Please update if you found some solutions to the problems.